# how to display categories in layered navigation magento?

Tags: magento, layered

already set up my categories as anchors active
My attributes are displayed correctly, more categories are not displaying.

can anyone help me?

thank you

Comment: Dear Tiago Martins, could you please tell us what problem you are trying to solve? What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check if the categories you want display is not empty. Magento hide the empty Categories.

Comment: Please remember you'll se only the sub-categories of the main category where you are in...

Comment: Make sure `Include in Navigation Menu` is enabled for the root category and the categories you want to show in layered navigation. After changing you need to reindex `catalog_category_flat` + clear the `block_html` cache.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your categories are a sub-category of the Default (Root) Category.
Magento creates your default category (make sure you don't delete this).  When you start to build out your navigation, create sub-categories and place them under your Default (Root) Category.